# Eclipse GEF. How to enforce single selection?

Tags: selection, eclipse-gef

How do I enforce single Selection in Eclipse GEF?

Only one EditPart should be selectable at a time.

Answer (score 0):

See [bug 102420](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102420)

That seems like the only way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Override getDragTracker in editPart:

```
 @Override
 public DragTracker getDragTracker(Request request)
 {
    // Create a drag tracker that will enforce single selection
    return new DragEditPartsTracker(this)
    {
        protected void performSelection()
        {
            if (hasSelectionOccurred())
                return;

            setFlag(FLAG_SELECTION_PERFORMED, true);
            getCurrentViewer().select(getSourceEditPart());
        }
    };
}
```